# Capturing the PID of a background process started by a Makefile

Tags: shell, makefile, sh, background-process

I have a Makefile that starts a Django web server. I would like the server to be started in the background, with the PID saved to a file.

My recipe looks like this:

```
run: venv
    @"${PYTHON}" "${APP}/manage.py" runserver 80
```

Intuitively, to background the process and capture the PID, I'd have to do something like this:

```
run: venv
    @"${PYTHON}" "${APP}/manage.py" runserver 80 & ; echo "$$!" > "${LOGDIR}/django.pid"
```

This doesn't work, though. The sub-shell that 'make' uses (/bin/sh in my case) works when you use:

```
<command> &
```

...to background a process, and works when use:

```
<command> ; <command>
```

(or `<command> && <command>`, etc...) to chain commands. However, when I try to background the first process and chain a second one, I get the following error:

`` /bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `;' ``

What is the best way to background a process and capture the PID in a Makefile?

Thanks
- B

Comment: I'm curious why you're using `make` to start a webserver? Is this some sort of test suite? Good luck!

Comment: @shelter: I'm working on a web app, and I'm using a Makefile to provide a quick way to start a local web server, for development and testing purposes.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just leave a single ampersand, without a semicolon after it:

```
run: venv
    @"${PYTHON}" "${APP}/manage.py" runserver 80 & echo "$$!" > "${LOGDIR}/django.pid"
```

Ampersand acts as command separator in the same way as a semicolon:

```
<command> & <command>
```

Answer (score 0):

If Make gives you too much trouble, you can always have the target launch an sh script; in that script, launch the process, background, and then output the pid to a file.

Comment: This could work, but since a makefile is just a set shell macro commands, I'd probably run into the same issue in my shell script. The solution there should be adapted directly into the makefile rather than adding another layer of abstraction and dependencies.

Comment: True. A lot of times I try to get it working in a shell script first, and then migrate it into the Makefile.