# Process not detaching when invoked from a Makefile

Tags: macos, unix, process, makefile

I'm trying to use a Makefile to launch a background process and save its PID to a file. This is what I have so far:

```
start:
        ./bin/provisioner & echo $$! > ./bin/prov.pid

end:
        kill `cat ./bin/prov.pid`
```

When I run `make start`, the process is started and the file is saved - but the *process does not detach from the shell*. The command hangs, which is the complete opposite of what I want. But if I copy the contents of the start block and run it independently in the shell:

```
./bin/provisioner & echo $$! > ./bin/prov.pid
```

it detaches fine. Why does it not work when run inside a Makefile?

There are three existing answers (listed below), but none of them work for me. I also tried to invoke a shell command by using `$(shell ...)` but that didn't work either. Can somebody help?

- [saving PID of spawned process within a Makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23366112/saving-pid-of-spawned-process-within-a-makefile)
- [Capturing the PID of a background process started by a Makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153653/capturing-the-pid-of-a-background-process-started-by-a-makefile)
- [Makefile run processes in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7668311/makefile-run-processes-in-background)

Comment: What does the detaching code in provisioner look like?

Comment: @EtanReisner When I run `make start` it hangs. When I run `./bin/provisioner & echo $$! > ./bin/prov.pid` it doesn't hang (i.e. it detaches and runs it as a background process).

Comment: Yes, you said that in the OP. I was asking about the code that handles the detaching in provisioner. Unless there isn't any and you meant "goes to the background". In which case does your command work if you use `/bin/sh './bin/provisioner & echo $$! > ./bin/prov.pid'`? If not that's the problem. `/bin/sh` isn't supporting job control and that's what make uses for shell commands by default.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "goes to the background" not detach. When I do `/bin/sh '...'` I get this output: ```/bin/sh: ./bin/provisioner & echo $! > ./bin/prov.pid: No such file or directory
make: *** [start] Error 127```

Comment: Blah. `/bin/sh -c '....'` sorry. Second time I forget that argument in the past ten minutes.

Comment: All the errors are gone now but it's still hanging :/ I don't know why it works in the shell but not from a Makefile. Weird...

Comment: You are using `bash` as your shell. `/bin/sh` (which is what make uses by default and what you used manually in my test) doesn't support job control and can't put things in the background like that. You can set `SHELL=/bin/bash` to get make to use bash instead or find some other way to do what you want (like not using make for this as it is a bad fit).

Comment: I'm using zsh. When I add `SHELL := /bin/bash` to the top of the Makefile it still hangs. What would be a good alternative to a Makefile do you think?

Comment: Hm... That should have worked I think... Oh well. Two shell scripts. `start.sh` and `stop.sh` or one that takes an argument (like `init.d` scripts) or anything of the sort.