# Starting and closing applications in Makefile

Tags: makefile

I use a Makefile to compile latex. In the end of the compile process I have the following rule

```
$(PDFREADER) $(SOURCE).pdf &
```

where it will open in *evince* the newly created pdf.

What I want is that next time I compile the pdf, the Makefile closes the current *evince* process, opened in during previous the compilation.

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23366112/saving-pid-of-spawned-process-within-a-makefile) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153653/capturing-the-pid-of-a-background-process-started-by-a-makefile) posts, but I did not understand how to do it.

Any help?

Thanks

**EDIT** this is the makefile I use

```
SOURCE=PEI
PDFREADER=evince
EXTENSIONS=ps dvi log out toc aux bbl blg idx glg glo ist lof acn ilg ind ist lot xdy synctex.gz glsdefs

$(SOURCE).pdf:  $(SOURCE).tex  bibliografia.bib
    if [ -a evince.PID ]; then \
        kill -TERM $$(cat evince.PID) || true; \
    fi;
    pdflatex -shell-escape $(SOURCE).tex
    bibtex $(SOURCE)
    pdflatex -shell-escape $(SOURCE).tex
    pdflatex -shell-escape $(SOURCE).tex

vis: $(SOURCE).pdf
    $(PDFREADER) $(SOURCE).pdf & echo $$! > evince.PID

clean: organized
    @rm -f $(SOURCE).pdf

organized:
    @rm -f $(foreach postfix, $(EXTENSIONS), $(SOURCE).$(postfix))
    @rm -f ./*~
    @cd ./tex && rm -rf $(foreach postfix, $(EXTENSIONS), *.$(postfix)) && rm -f ./*~
```

Comment: What about those answers are you having trouble with? Did you try adding the appropriate `echo` bits to your recipe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you start your process you have to store the process id (pid) to a file, let me call it `evince.PID`. So change your line in:

```
$(PDFREADER) $(SOURCE).pdf & echo $$! > evince.PID
```

This saves the pid in the `evince.PID` file. To stop the previous process just read the pid from that file (if exists) and kill the corresponding process. To do this add to you makefile:

```
if [ -a evince.PID ]; then \
    kill -TERM $$(cat evince.PID) || true; \
fi;
```

For future makefile/bash writing notice that:

- `$$!` corresponds to the bash variable `$!`, as the makefile syntax also indicates variables with `$` to disambiguate a bash variable we need a double `$$`
- `$$(cat evince.PID)` reads the file into a bash variable, again marked with `$$`
- `kill -TERM` returns a non 0 exit code if the process does not exist (e.g. you already killed it by hand). With `|| true` a 0 exit code is returned even if kill failed, so a failed kill does not cause the makefile to fail

Edit:
My bad, I figured out that `-a` to check if a file exists is now deprecated and should be avoided in favor of `-e`. Debian Almquist shell (`dash`) seems to be a bit picky about this. To kill the process then use:

```
if [ -e evince.PID ]; then \
    kill -TERM $$(cat evince.PID) || true; \
fi;
```

Comment: The explanation is great, but for some reason I get
`/bin/sh: 1: [: -a: unexpected operator`
I put it inside the rule that compiles the pdf

Comment: It works here. Can you produce a simple makefile that reproduces the problem and add it as an edit to your question?

Comment: @Camandros I edited my answer to address the `/bin/sh: 1: [: -a: unexpected operator` error. `-a` is now deprecated and should be replaced with `-e`. Strangely, only running make with a `dash` shell triggers the error.